# NodeJS app for end-user distribution

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for the proper way to distribute/deploy a node.js app that would run as a small webserver on the user's machine.

Is there a stub method or install script or a "install wizard" that would download all `node_modules` dependencies, download the latest nodejs binary, set up the environment, etc... or I have to distribute it bulk with everything packed? Is there any guide for that purpose?

Comment: Sounds like you wanna build something out with electron https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: In the scenario, if I ship it within the Electron, it will bundle everything in one pack going over 100Mb. While the actual script pack is just under 1Mb. The Stub installer would download everything (node binary and modules) from the user's computer. That would avoid a nightmare to update the huge pack with all bundled every time a new module version is out or a new node.js binary version is available.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer) app for example, it does the Electron way. **A simple "desktop dimmer" to reduce screen bright program is over 100Mb to download and over 250Mb to install**. It includes the browser + the modules + the (**outdated**) nodejs binary. That can't be real. After installing this app you'd realize most of it is outdated. And it would only have new versions on it when the author publishes his own scripts a new version (so he would have to bundle everything in one package all over again).

Comment: This is only for OSX, but it looks more like what you want: https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap1

Comment: @JeremyJackson Electron was a nice try but it is just unnaceptable. It takes 130Mb on its own and takes ages to launch. I'm refering to Electron **alone** - not counting the loading of any app on it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edited :

You could install `node` and `npm`, download your dependencies by running `npm install` in the command line (first declare them within your `package.json`) only *then* users can run your script. This is how you do development in Node.js, or deploy to a development server. See [using npm](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-npm-tutorial/). You could automate that with a shell script if that is what you are after.

However, when distributing programs to end-users that might not be the best approach. Linux users are used to a package (.deb for instance) and Windows users are used to an .exe or a setup wizard.

That is why I recommended the tools below. I also assumed you were targeting Windows as this is less of a problem is unix-like environments.

If you want a single file (.exe), [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) and [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) are made for that purpose. These Node.js tools are used by the developer to **compile** JavaScript code into a single executable binary that is convenient for end-users and Windows deployment. The resulting .exe file is very light and does not require node to be installed on the end-user’s computers.

[Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) along with [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) can produce setup wizards, but it installs a lot of files even for the smallest program. Your program will include all of `node` and `webkit`, that is why it produces heavy installs.

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) can also create a setup wizard, it is simple and does common stuff well (copying files, running shell scripts).

---

Original answer:

Short answer is: **not really**.

You have to keep in mind that Javascript is and has always been interpreted, so until recently never compiled to binary as you might do with other languages. Some exploration has been going on, but essentially you won’t get a "good practice" answer.

The long answer is, **maybe**, for some limited use cases:

- There is the fresh new **[pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg)** that does exactly this, and it looks promising.
- There has been **[nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe)** for a while, it works great for some use cases (maybe yours). Native/compiled modules are still an issue however.
- **[Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron)** might work for a full blown app with a significant user interface, but it is not light or compact.

You could always use browserify to concatenate and uglify all your code with the modules you use and then make an installer with something like **[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net)** to setup node and your script. Native modules would still be a problem however.

Comment: The modules/dependecies can be installed by issuing the command `npm install` which will automatically download and install the dependecines listed in `package.json`. Latest npm can be downloaded from https://github.com/npm/npm/archive/latest.zip

Comment: pkg and nexe both require nodejs to be installed. It must be some "install wizard" that will download and install nodejs. The end-user may not even know what nodejs is.

Comment: pkg and nexe are used in development, they are tools that let you compile your script into an executable binary without dependency on node or npm, that does not require installation of any dependencies and it is intended for distribution